# typescript: using enum values in interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that uses an enum value in one of its fields:

```
export enum AnimalType {
    DOG,
    CAT,
}


export interface DogAttrs {
    bones: boolean,
    type: AnimalType.DOG
}
```

and my goal is a function that creates dogs and adds them to the list of dogs.

```
function addDog(animalList: DogAttrs[]) {
    const animal = {
        type: AnimalType.DOG,
        bones: true
    }
    animalList.push(animal);   
}
```

but this function says the object I create is wrong and it does not conform to the `DogAttrs` interface:

```
Type 'AnimalType' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.
```

why is that? and how to fix this?

live example:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEEFkEt0CGANgCoCeEICA3sAvQgCIDyA4ggLwIDkLr3AGjoMAwlhKceYkoOABfYIvDR4CXMjggYAMwIBjKoygBzLHDgwAzjWH0ARlGQhLALgQOoREAWRCGCOAoQN142bnlFRW1UZD04XEcEAgATZKNjAAoffGIAGVxLODd0swtLAG0AXQBKG389R0KkvEIiSVp-f0DKNxwc0iCAOj4-TvtHZzcLVBBbBAV-bNb8wsGIVEsACyyW4mqAbgYIyOAgA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that typescript will widen the type of the constant when you assign them to the variable. The simple solution is to use an `as const` assertion or to specify the type of the constant explicitly:

```
function addDog(animalList: DogAttrs[]) {
    const animal: DogAttrs = {
        type: AnimalType.DOG,
        bones: true
    }
    animalList.push(animal);   
}
```

Or

```
function addDog(animalList: DogAttrs[]) {
    const animal = {
        type: AnimalType.DOG,
        bones: true
    } as const
    animalList.push(animal);   
}
```